# getKeyCode() method error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In this code I want to get the Key or the code of the keyPressed on that textField but it shows error as follows

[image: Error while Compiling the code]

Here is my code

```
textFieldC.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
      int code = textFieldC.getKeyCode();
      // String ch = textFieldC.getKeyChar();
      labelResult.setText("code");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Looks like `tectFieldC` is of type `TextField` ([awt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html)?) and it doesn't have the method: `getKeyCode()`

Comment: Yes it's of awt type , I have imported all the required classes @alfasin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class which can give you that key code is [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode()), not the `TextField`. So change this line:

```
int code = textFieldC.getKeyCode();
```

to this:

```
int code = ke.getKeyCode();
```

Comment: yeah it worked but still it's just printing "Code" , not the actual keyCode of the Pressed key which is required @Juan

Comment: That's because you are printing the string literal "code", not the content of the variable `code`.  Your setText should be: `labelResult.setText("" + code);` or `labelResult.setText(String.valueOf(code));`